# How to skip things in VBA excel to outlook macro

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

So far i have got working a macro to send out emails to everyone in my excel list and it works fine except i need to add a couple more things to it:

1, Send the email to people ONLY if the date in *Cells(r, 4).Value* is between Today + 7 days and Today + 14 days otherwise skip that row.

2, If email has been sent change value of *Cells(r, 20).Value* from "False" to "True"

3, Skip rows were *Cells(r, 20).Value* is "True"

Heres how it loos so far:

```
  Sub SetupAppointmentList()
' adds a list of appontments to the Calendar in Outlook
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olAppItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim r As Long
    DeleteNotices ' deletes previous test appointments
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If olApp Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Outlook is not available!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If




    r = 10 ' first row with data in
    While Len(Cells(r, 1).Formula) > 0
        Set olAppItem = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
        With olAppItem

            .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
            ' set default appointment values
            .Start = Now
            .End = Now
            .Subject = "No subject"
            .Location = ""
            .Body = ""
            .ReminderSet = True
            On Error Resume Next
            .Recipients.Add Cells(r, 3).Value
            .Recipients.ResolveAll
            .Start = Cells(r, 4).Value + Cells(r, 5).Value
            .End = Cells(r, 4).Value + Cells(r, 6).Value
            .Subject = "Interview"
            .Location = Cells(r, 13).Value + ", " + Cells(r, 14).Value
            .Body = "Hi.... Blah Blah Blah"
            .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 30
            .Categories = "Notice"            
     On Error GoTo 0
            .Save
            .Display
            '.Send


        End With
        r = r + 1
    Wend
    Set olAppItem = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hope you can Help, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than write the code for you here's what you do:

Get the content of Cells(r, 4) and use CDate to convert it to a date. Compare it to your start and end dates and if its in the range, continue.

Get content of (r, 20) and use CBool to get the bool value. Check and if OK continue.

After sending the email, just set Cells(r, 20) = true

Try that and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks, im still very new to vba stuff. Im not entirly sure how or where in my code i need to put this.